# Ruby Savon - Parse XML string

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, sinatra

I have exhausted google on this subject and I just can't seem to get it right..
I have the following XML payload returned from Savon:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:listGFUsersResponse xmlns:ns="http://ws.fds.com">
            <ns:return>
                 &lt;responseCode>0000&lt;/responseCode>&lt;responseDescription>No Errors-DWI&lt;/responseDescription>&lt;user>&lt;login>aa1283&lt;/login>&lt;name>Andrew Alonzo&lt;/name>&lt;team>DIALER&lt;/team>&lt;secLev>-1&lt;/secLev>&lt;maxDiscount>0.00&lt;/maxDiscount>&lt;phoneSystemId>&lt;/phoneSystemId>&lt;/user>&lt;user>&lt;login>aaronc&lt;/login>&lt;name>Aaron Callison&lt;/name>&lt;team>&lt;/team>&lt;secLev>-1&lt;/secLev>&lt;maxDiscount>0.00&lt;/maxDiscount>&lt;phoneSystemId>&lt;/phoneSystemId>&lt;/user>
            </ns:return>
        </ns:listGFUsersResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I would like to parse out ALL values of `<name> * </name>` and `<login> * </login>`

A few of my attempts here:

```
response1 = client1.call(
  :list_gf_users,
  message: message)


doc = Nokogiri::XML(response1.to_s)
pp doc
p doc.search('/name').text
p doc.search('/login').text
```

Nothing returned...

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(response1.to_s)
value = doc.xpath('/name').map(&:text)
puts value
```

Nada....

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(response1.to_s)
value = doc.xpath('/user[name]').map(&:text)
puts value
```

Zilch...

would love to be able to see:

```
name: Andrew Alonzo
login: aa1283
```

or even better a Hash?

```
{"aa1283" => "Andrew Alonzo"}
```

Getting 0 results such as:

```
""
[]
nil
```

Comment: Your xml is invalid.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not super helpful... what is invalid? What is the suggested fix? Any work around, as I'm strictly piping the response from the API...Assuming it's invalid, is it a string and can I parse it the same way(turn it into a hash)? As the title states, I believe it is a string in some form of XML or the alike, how should I parse it accordingly?!

Comment: Add the full xml you're receiving, and note it's escaping characters.

Comment: It's over 500 users long, I've included the ending xml portion...

Comment: @SebastianPalma Just because I couldn't stand looking at that I have editted the question

Comment: @Shwtm3 I believe you should be calling `response1.body` not `reponse1.to_s`

Comment: Sadly.. thats not the form its being received as.. I've seen many examples of XML payload as you edited, but my payload isn't behaving like that... 

I was able to use Nokogiri to remove the escaped characters:  
`user>login>zd5436/login>name>Zack Duello/name>team>PWMM/team>secLev>2/secLev>maxDiscount>0.00/maxDiscount>phoneSystemId>/phoneSystemId>/user>`  
However; still unable to get the values I need :/

Comment: @Shwtm3 that XML is invalid and probably due to the call `to_s` not the actual response recieved Sidenote `savon` uses `nokogiri` and `response1.doc` will already be a parsed `Nokogiri::XML` [Source](https://github.com/savonrb/savon/blob/master/lib/savon/response.rb#L63)

Comment: Na, I just get an error, tried that:  
   

`doc = Nokogiri::XML(response1)
   pp doc`  


`/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/document.rb:62:in read_memory\': no implicit conversion of Savon::Response into String (TypeError)`  

My initial post, is what comes from Savon directly...
   `response1 = client1.call(
   :list_gf_users,
   message: message)

   pp response1`

Comment: You are not listening. please call `doc = response1.doc` no `Nokogiri` at all

Comment: `   response1 = client1.call(
   :list_gf_users,
   message: message)

   pp response1`

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soapenv:Body><ns:listGFUsersResponse xmlns:ns=\"http://ws.fds.com\"><ns:return>&lt;responseCode>0000&lt;/responseCode>&lt;responseDescription>No Errors-DWI&lt;/responseDescription>&lt;user>&lt;login>aa1283&lt;/login>&lt;name>Andrew Alonzo&lt;/name>...`

Its the same format... I am listening...

Comment: Did you try `response1.doc`? Additionally you can use `response1.body.gsub("&lt;","<")` if that is really the response (which is invalid XML). This will replace the html encoded less than with an actual "<" and then it will be parseable

Comment: `doc = response1.doc`

Looks better but still not sure how to parse:  

`"<responseCode>0000</responseCode><responseDescription>No Errors-DWI</responseDescription><user><login>aa1283</login><name>Andrew Alonzo</name><team>DIALER</team><secLev>-1</secLev><maxDiscount>0.00</maxDiscount><phoneSystemId></phoneSystemId></user><user><login>aaronc</login><name>Aaron Callison</name><team></team><secLev>-1</secLev><maxDiscount>0.00</maxDiscount><phoneSystemId></phoneSystemId></user>`

Seems like a flat string...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... probably not most efficient but gets the job done:

Convert Savon response to string(can't use scan on Savon output)
`doc = response1.to_s
subFile = doc.gsub("&lt;","<")` #Replace the string convert characters

Run scan using regex capture groups:
`@user = subFile.scan /<user><login>(.+?)<\/login><name>(.*?)<\/name>.+?><\/user>/`

Answer (score 0):

In your comments you have

```
doc = response1.doc
```

which gives you a Nokogiri document. With that you should be able to do the following:

```
doc.xpath("//user").each do |user|
  login = user.at("login")&.text
  name = user.at("name")&.text
  puts "#{login}: #{name}"
end
```

The output is

```
aa1283: Andrew Alonzo
aaronc: Aaron Callison
```

I used the XML from your comment:

```
<root>
  <responseCode>0000</responseCode>
  <responseDescription>No Errors-DWI</responseDescription>
  <user>
    <login>aa1283</login>
    <name>Andrew Alonzo</name>
    <team>DIALER</team>
    <secLev>-1</secLev>
    <maxDiscount>0.00</maxDiscount>
    <phoneSystemId></phoneSystemId>
  </user>
  <user>
    <login>aaronc</login>
    <name>Aaron Callison</name>
    <team></team>
    <secLev>-1</secLev>
    <maxDiscount>0.00</maxDiscount>
    <phoneSystemId></phoneSystemId>
  </user>
</root>
```

Note that I had to convert this to plaintext. You have some non-printing unicode characters sprinkled throughout the document in seemingly random places (which makes me wonder if that's actually the cause of your problems).